# Accessing wordpress posts with nice urls using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a wordpress site that currently shows the posts like

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?p=1
```

and now i wanna access the same thing by writing url as

```
http://mysite.com/1
```

what can be the rewrite rules to do that.. i saw the .htaccess that hides the index.php from the url and regular expressions but was not being able to properly do what is needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, preferably before any wordpress related rewrite rules, add these:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: altought it works, can you please explain the last line in details so that i dnt have to bang my heads again?

Comment: @praveen Sure. Using the regular expression, `^/?([0-9]+)$` to match against the URI, it says: Start of the URI (`^`) can optionally be a `/`, then one or more numbers (0-9), then the end of the URI (`$`). The numbers are grouped using parens, so we can backreference them using a `$1`. If the URI matches that regular expression, internally rewrite the URI to `/index.php?p=$1`, where `$1` is the backreference to the grouping of numbers in the regex match. The `L` means to stop rewriting for this iteration, and the `QSA` means if there's a query string, append it.